# Java Spring Boot JPA MongoRepository - handling missing attributes

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa

**OnwebsiteNot** returns json  when the onWebsite attribute exists as well as when it does not exist.

How do I adjust this query to return on json only when the onwebsite attribute exists

```
public interface DdsJsonRepositoryOnWebsite extends MongoRepository<DdsJson, Integer> {

  Page<DdsJson> findByAdditionalfields_**OnwebsiteNot**AndAdditionalfields_Process(String onwebsite, int process, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exists` modifier like this:

```
public interface DdsJsonRepositoryOnWebsite extends MongoRepository<DdsJson, Integer> {

  Page<DdsJson> findByAdditionalfields_**OnwebsiteExists**AndAdditionalfields_Process(String onwebsite, int process, Pageable pageable);

}
```